# On my desktop my folder and file icons do not display the file names

Tags: nautilus, unity-2d

I upgraded to 11.10 and using Unity 2D.
My desktop consists of icons of folders and files.
Prior to the upgrade, all folder and files had file names underneath.
The names have all disappeared now and all I see are icons.

I would like to bring back the file names.
How do I do that?

I tried compizconfig, and a few other options without any success.

After trying my solution to the problem for some reason the desktop reverted back to how it was before.

I do not know why.

Answer (score 3):

Use DConf editor (`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`) install it if you don't have it installed.

Go to org>gnome>nautilus>desktop edit the value for `text-ellipsis-limit` to 0 (zero).

> An integer specifying how parts of overlong file names should be replaced by ellipses on the desktop. If the number is larger than 0, the file name will not exceed the given number of lines. If the number is 0 or smaller, no limit is imposed on the number of displayed lines.

My original value was set to 3, which prevented the file names from being shown for some odd reason.  Likely a Nautilus bug.